# Is there a way to determine whether a specified dir is in removable sdcard?

Tags: android

On some phones, there are two external storage directories. For example, on some phones, there are `/sdcard(internal storage)` and `/sdcard/external_sd` (removable stick or others). These two directores may differ on different phones, for example, there may be `/sdcard` and `/sdcard/_External_SD`.

My question is, for a given directory, is there any way to determine where it is mounted? i.e., how to find whether this dir is mounted on `/sdcard` or `/sdcard/external_sd`. regex shouldn't work well as the directories names are different on different phones. Using this code:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Just returns the "primary" external storage directory, so it doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `mount` command output helps.

The following gives you (the first) alternate external storage path:

```
String getAlternateExternalStoragePath() {
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();    
        process.waitFor();

        String sdcardPath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+ on (" + sdcardPath + ".+) type vfat");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output.toString());

        if (matcher.find()) return matcher.group(1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

// ...

String alternateExternalStoragePath = getAlternateExternalStoragePath();
```